# In ASP .NET Core 3.1, WebAPIs, what is the most logical place to do JSON request validation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm writing a few .NET core 3.1 WebAPIs, and although model validation (through ValidationAttributes) takes care of most of my request validation, the request validation doesn't respect the DataTypeAttribute.

So for example, if I have a property that is a decimal on my end-point and someone provides a string, it fails at request validation and my controller end-point doesn't get hit.

I know there are a few alternatives, and I'm just wondering where it would make the most sense to put request validation logic in?

Examples: ValidationAttribute (doesn't fire for request validation), ActionFilters (OnActionExecuting, which does fire), JsonInputFormatters (also fires), etc...

========== EDIT: ==========

Thank you for the answers. I now am creating a subclass CustomActionFilterAttribute from ActionFilterAttribute. Then I decorate my controller and its actions with this filter attribute, but the OnActionExecuting isn't firing.

I have tried to do (in Startup.ConfigureServices()):

```
services.AddScoped\<CustomActionFilterAttribute>();

services.AddControllers(
                config =>
                {
                    config.Filters.Add\<CustomActionFilterAttribute>();
                });
```

And then I decorate my controller like so:

```
[ValidateSubUsersModelFilter]
public class MyController : Controller {}
```

None of the actions in MyController trigger the OnActionExecuting function of CustomActionFilterAttribute. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example in HttpMethods

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}/{year:min(2000)}/{month:range(1,2)})"
```

or ValidationFilter

```
 public class Validation : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               //This is my custom Error Model
                ErrorDTO error = new ErrorDTO();
                error.status = 400;

                var ModelErrors = context.ModelState.Keys.ToList();
                var Errors = context.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < Errors.Count; i++)
                {
                    error.Errors.Add($"{ModelErrors[i]} {Errors[i].ErrorMessage}");
                }

               
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(error);


            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

DataTypeAttribute isn't used for validation, but I still think this problem comes under the heading of model validation. Couldn't you just add a custom validator on this property? e.g. (untested):

```
public class DecimalValidator : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {       
        decimal result;
        return value != null && decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, my ValidationAttributes only hit "IsValid" after the request has been validated. This in turns returns the generic message from the JSON serializer of "could not convert field to decimal" Ideally, I'd like to intercept the validation at the request point.

Answer (score 1):

I would use fluent validation and set up automatic request validation during mvc   setup. That way every json request will be validated if body model will have validator implemented before it hits the controller.